# Which feat Combo can give the most number of ranged attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optimization

What feats can I take to give me the largest number of ranged attacks per turn?

I know Rapid Shot and Many Shot are good for ranged attacks,

but

Two Weapon Fighting, Improved Two Weapon Fighting, Greater Two Weapon Fighting can also be used for thrown weapons.

Assume sufficient ammo is available. Which of these two feat paths would result in the larger number of attacks?

Comment: Is the question "out of these two options" or "which combo in general"? I'm sure our local char-op experts can squeeze out a lot more ranged attacks if you're interested in that.

Comment: When you say 'ranged attacks', are you locked into a weapon yet? The Lash ability of the Pyrokineticist allows BOTH of these feat chains to work in tandem.

Comment: @WeckarE. At least in D&D 3.5 and Pathfinder (unsure about the other two systems), any thrown weapon (or otherwise light/one-handed ranged weapon, like pistols) can benefit from both. Very difficult to actually have enough feats for all of them though.

Comment: Closing; the scope of this question is unclear. We don't know whether this is about the theoretical max number of ranged attacks via feats (even if it's neither of those feat combinations), or whether it's about picking exclusively between those two different sets of feats (even if neither are the theoretical max). The title and opening sentence suggest the first interpretation; the rest suggests the second. In a practical scenario, it would also be useful to know what base race/class build we're operating on, in case it makes any differences. Please clarify, then we can reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Pathfinder - Rapid Shot can be used with thrown weapons, Assuming you have the quickdraw feat, or enough hands or a method to have all thrown weapons drawn at the time of attack.

> When making a full-attack action with a ranged weapon, you can fire one additional time this round at your highest bonus.

Thrown Weapons are indeed ranged weapons, So assuming quantity of attacks is what you are going for, thrown twf is likely your best bet.

I am not as familiar with other systems to answer for them.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for and truly answered the question of which of the comb of feats has the more number of attacks. Thanks.

Comment: Thats all well and good, but please edit your question and tags to make it more clear for anyone who wishes to visit this page for information in the future! That way your question can also stop having negative points!

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver It also allows other answers which can help further increase the feat-based attack multiplication, since your question would then not need to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

From memory in Pathfinder the maximum number of arrows you can send down range is 8 with seven attack rolls, that's with a full-attack, Rapid Shot, Many Shot, and Haste, or the effects thereof. There are several (notably the psionic Marksman) classes with abilities that allow you to fire more for specific effects but for attacks on a target that's the max with a bow as Erudaki mentioned you can stack Two-Weapon Fighting and Rapid shot which will get you up to 8 attack rolls and the same 8 hits as the bow progression assuming the same spell effect is included.